# How to get text of element in a variable using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-parsing, selector

```
var markup = '<div class="ExternalClass34E9F553C2F74AA2B6D693A07BA166AC">Employee Self-Service pages have been corrected but may require you to refresh the page.</div><div class="ExternalClass34E9F553C2F74AA2B6D693A07BA166AC">&#160;</div><div class="ExternalClass34E9F553C2F74AA2B6D693A07BA166AC">If the problem remains, follow <a href="/Shared%20Documents/EBS%20Page%20Refresh%20Instructions_rkc.pdf">these instructions</a>. &#160;</div>';           
var str = "";
$(markup).find("div[class^='ExternalClass']").each(function(){
    str += $(this).text();
})
```

How do I grab content of all the divs in the `markup` that starts with `ExternalClass`?

Comment: Do you want to parse HTML or a javascript string? Because you say you want to parse the string, but your jQuery selector looks like you're parsing HTML nodes.

Comment: @user2415266  Updated. parse the variable, please

Comment: But all divs in variable start with `ExternalClass`.

Comment: Sorry just realised the class isn't 'ExternalClass' but begins with External Class. But then this just makes me wonder why you have so many classes, that all start with ExternalClass and all use really complex names?

Comment: @DibsyJr I have absolutely no control over the markup- controls emit the markup like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuerys `.find()` only loops through the children of the specific HTML you selected. Your variable `markup` has no children with the fitting class selector.
The easiest way I can imagine getting this solved, is to wrap all you have in `markup` inside another div, and then use your jQuery selector - that works:

```
var markup = '<div class="ExternalClass34E9F553C2F74AA2B6D693A07BA166AC">Employee Self-Service pages have been corrected but may require you to refresh the page.</div><div class="ExternalClass34E9F553C2F74AA2B6D693A07BA166AC">&#160;</div><div class="ExternalClass34E9F553C2F74AA2B6D693A07BA166AC">If the problem remains, follow <a href="/Shared%20Documents/EBS%20Page%20Refresh%20Instructions_rkc.pdf">these instructions</a>. &#160;</div>';
markup = '<div>' + markup + '</div>';
var str = "";
$(markup).find("div[class^='ExternalClass']").each(function(){
    str += $(this).text();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(markup)` selector contain all `ExternalClass` class and you can't use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) because it doen't any matched child. You need to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter selected element.

```
var markup = "<div...";
var str = "";
$(markup).filter("div[class^='ExternalClass']").each(function(){
    str += $(this).text();
})
```

```js
var markup = '<div class="ExternalClass34E9F553C2F74AA2B6D693A07BA166AC">Employee Self-Service pages have been corrected but may require you to refresh the page.</div><div class="ExternalClass34E9F553C2F74AA2B6D693A07BA166AC">&#160;</div><div class="ExternalClass34E9F553C2F74AA2B6D693A07BA166AC">If the problem remains, follow <a href="/Shared%20Documents/EBS%20Page%20Refresh%20Instructions_rkc.pdf">these instructions</a>. &#160;</div>';
$(markup).filter("div[class^='ExternalClass']").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That actually would be the correct answer here. Mine is bad in comparison.